# Extjs grid state false set around render

Tags: extjs, extjs4

In Extjs 4.0.7 I have a common grid with extra functions... the grid needs to load and set its saved state. I hide the columns, than close the grid, open the grid, columns are hidden (but when I open it, a set function is called with not hidden columns), than close again and open, and the all columns are not hidden again couse of the set before. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: we need some code to work around.

Answer (score 0):

We had a getColumns function overrided, I gave an other name to this